# What's the correct way to create an DAO class for an a composition class

Tags: java, inheritance, design-patterns, dao, composition

I am doing this 'B' class that have 'C' and/or 'D' class common attributes that I will implement in their parent class 'A', like client and employee that inherits person values, in this case, I am replacing inheritance for composition, for now I don't want to use a ORM framework, will I have an BDAO and CDAO, that evokes ADAO to make association in BD or create every A attribute in an B and C table?

```
 public class A{
 public long ID;
 public int attributeA;
 }
 public class B{
 public long ID;
 public int attributeB;
 A a = new A();
 }
 public class C{
 public long ID;
 public int attributeC;
 A a = new A();     
 }

 public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
 B bObject = new B();
 bObject.attributeB=0;
 A aObject = new A();
 aObject.attributeA=1;
 bObject.A=a;
 }
 }

 public class BDAO{
 public void add(B b){
 Conn.preparedStatement("insert into bTable (id,attributeB,FK_idA) 
values("b.ID+","+b.attributeB+","+b.A.id+")").execute();
 new ADAO().add(B.a);
 }
 }

 public class CDAO{
 public void add(C C){
 Conn.preparedStatement(...
 new ADAO().add(A.a);
 }
 }

 public class ADAO{
 public void add(A a){
 Conn.preparedStatement("insert into aTable (id,attributeA)
 values ("a.ID+","+a.attributeA+")").execute();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 14 and above you can use `record` classes for creating DO .

```
public record A(long ID, int attributeA){}
public record B(long ID, int attributeB, A a){}
public record C(long ID, int attributeC, A a){}
```

You will not have to write getter methods and other stuff.
 For more info refer https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/records-come-to-java

[Tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/record.html)

Comment: This is unrelated to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [composite design pattern](https://www.oodesign.com/composite-pattern.html) and [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) like this:

```java
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
class A {
    public long ID;
    public int attributeA;
}

@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
class B {
    public long ID;
    public int attributeB;
}

@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
class C {
    public long ID;
    public int attributeC;
}

// DTO class
@AllArgsConstructor
class ABC {
    public long ID;
    public int attributeA;
    public int attributeB;
    public int attributeC;
}

class ADAO{
    public void add(A a){
        // query
        System.out.println("add a: " + a);
    }
}

class BDAO{
    public void add(B b){
        // query
        System.out.println("add b: " + b);
    }
}


class CDAO{
    public void add(C c){
        // query
        System.out.println("add c: " + c);
    }
}

// composite class
@AllArgsConstructor
class ABCService {
    private final ADAO adao;
    private final BDAO bdao;
    private final CDAO cdao;

    public void add(ABC abc) {
        adao.add(new A(abc.ID, abc.attributeA));
        bdao.add(new B(abc.ID, abc.attributeB));
        cdao.add(new C(abc.ID, abc.attributeC));
    }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ABCService abcService = new ABCService(new ADAO(), new BDAO(), new CDAO());
        abcService.add(new ABC(1, 123, 456, 789));
    }
}
```

Comment: B contains A and C contains A.